# Intent para marcar número télefonico

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo el `Intent` para realizar una llamada :

```
int numero=66666699;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
//intent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
intent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + numero));
startActivity(intent);
```

pero yo no quiero que directamente llame sino que le muestre el numero en la marcacion como en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se puede realizar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad es similar a como lo estas realizando, pero no necesitas definir un packagename: `intent.setPackage("com.android.server.telecom");`.

Si realizas este `Intent`. se mostrará el número esperando des click en el botón para realizar la llamada:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL).setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tel)));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Muy importante comentar que esta forma de abrir la pantalla para marcación telefónica no requiere de ningún permiso.